# python pandas assigning to existing dataframe in iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I have a long list of files that I want to load into separate data frames. However pandas seems to do nothing like that in line, so I am struggling to do this. In my example below, file_map would actually be imported so I can't have a static mapping between variable and file_name. The example does not achieve what i am looking for because in the loop, pyhton creates a new variable df. Is there somehow a way to actually point at the old variable from the dictionary and set this to whatever pd.read_csv returns?

```
columns = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
df_d1 = pd.DataFrame()
df_d2 = pd.DataFrame()


file_map = {
    'data_1.csv': df_d1,
    'data_2.csv': df_d2,
}


for file_name , df in file_map.items():

    df = pd.read_csv(path + file_name,
                 header=None,
                 sep=";",
                 names=columns,
                 parse_dates = {'dateTime': ['c1']},
                 )
```

Alternatively, are there better ways to generally handle this than what I am doing here? Suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that works well in practice:

```
import glob
import os

dataframes = {}
for fn in glob('/path/to/files/<pattern>.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(fn, ...)
    dataframes[os.path.basename(fn)] = df
```

Here `dataframes` is a dictionary of dataframes. I'm using `glob` to get the actual file list, but of course this list can come from anywhere. `os.path.basename` returns just the filename, without the `/path/to/files` part.

alternatively if you want all the data in the same dataframe you can also do:

```
data = None
for fn in glob('/path/to/files/<pattern>.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(fn, ...)
    df['source'] = os.path.basename(fn)
    data = pd.concat([data, df]) if data is not None else df
```

Here `data` at the end of the loop is a dataframe with all data. Of course this assumes the files are of the same content type, i.e. you actually want one dataframe.

Comment: The only addition I could make is to take filenames from `sys.argv`.

Comment: ah, so, your filenames are saved under a name you know and can work with?. I do not necessarily know the filenames or have any control over them. This is why I tried to map them to df_1, ... .

Comment: not sure if I understand your intention here. the above is independent of the file names... if you get the list of filenames from somewhere else, just replace `glob(...)` with the list of the actual names.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. I think I need to be able to guarantee the order of the filenames since df1 and df2 are not interchangeable, but I can actually do that, thanks